# Can we ban the D8 tag?

Tags: feature-request

I have edited all the D8 tagged questions to be tagged 8 instead. Can we disallow D8 somehow? I am not a moderator yet and I can't find a tool to report a tag to moderators either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, I merged D8 into 8, and made them [synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work), with 8 being the master.  So, in theory, D8 will never appear again.